# Android - Disable scrolling while holding button

Tags: android, android-button, ontouchlistener, android-scrollview, motionevent

I'v got a `Button` inside a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        <Button/>
        ...
    <LinearLayout/>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm using this button for recoding voice. When it catches `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event, I start recording, and on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event I stop it.

```
buttomRecord.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            startRecording();
            return true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            stopRecording();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is when user is recording voice, if this `ScrollView` scrolls down or up, this button will loose focus and will never catch `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event.

How can I lock focus on `Button` while I'm holding it or disable `ScrollView` scrolling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

to disallow touch event of `scrollview`

So your code will be

```
    buttomRecord.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            startRecording();
            mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            stopRecording();
            mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom scroll view:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

private boolean mScrollable = true;

public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mScrollable = enabled;
}

public boolean isScrollable() {
    return mScrollable;
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
            if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
            return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
    // we are not scrollable
    if (!mScrollable) return false;
    else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}}
```

And then in your xml:

```
<your.package.name.CustomScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            Android: scrollbars="vertical">
   <!--whatever widgets you want to add-->
</your.package.name.CustomScrollView>
```

In your activity:

```
buttomRecord.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            scrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
            startRecording();
            return true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            stopRecording();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not a good solution while there is a just-one-line-code solution... See the correct answer... thanks anyway ;)